# Resources Bundle not getting into IPA when I add a framework

Tags: ios, mobileiron

I have included a framework from MobilIron in my application. This question is a general one. As part of the development process, I have added AppConnect.framework to my project. I have also added AppConnectResources.bundle to my project. The resource bundle also contains AppConnect.plist. I have copied the bundle into my project.

I added AppConnect.framework to Linked Frameworks and Libraries on the General tab for the build target.

I have also added the correct Framework Search Paths and Library Search Paths to the Build Settings tab for the build target.

The project builds without errors. I next export the IPA file. I next use a shell script from MobileIron that simple checks if AppConnection.plist file is in the AppConnectResources.bundle. The script cannot find the plist file so it seems like the resources.bundle file is not getting put into the IPA.

I have spent many hours trying to figure this problem out without success.

Your suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: In Xcode, select your target and go under the 'Build Phases' tab. There, look at 'Copy Bundle Resources' and ensure whatever you want copied is added there.

Comment: I failed to mention that I did have the resources bundle where you specified.